# when i bevel this circular edge, the extrussion looks weird

Tags: bevel

when i bevel this circular edge, the extrussion looks weird how can i solve it?

[image]

[image]

file here

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you don't have overlapping vertices (press M > Merge by Distance) and also recalculate the normals (Shift N), if it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: tried both of those and nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "floating" vertices that make you miss some edges when you select the edge loop, dissolve them:

[image]

also merge this vertex to this one (and maybe clean your topology a bit more):

[image]

The bevel should work:

[image]

Draw this edge to avoid artefacts, rearrange the topology (still a bit trash in my screenshot though):

[image]

Comment: i got this weird shading: https://prnt.sc/mH1aLIN_vXXU topology:  2 shading weird: https://prnt.sc/YV8KSuVZLnho

Comment: In the Object Data panel > Normals > enable Auto Smooth and tweak a bit the Angle value? Or please share your file again

Comment: i have shade auto smooth and also i have weighted normals

Comment: please share your file again